# 'spatstat' 'envelope'-object cannot be assessed by dclf.test (error: wrong number of rows)

Tags: spatstat

I have spatio-temporal data for shrub colonisation, due to a very high number of individuals restricted to three polygonal transects (5m wide, 60-100m long, spaced ~30m apart). I am analysing the data in 'spatstat' version 1.58-2.

I want to assess the clustering between individuals, both total (all mapped individuals) and in subsequent cohorts (recruits vs. established in 7 subsequent periods), by 'pcfinhom' & 'pcfcross.inhom'.
I have created 'envelope'-objects with arguments 'savefuns = T' and 'savepatterns = T' for latter assessment by DCLF-test, for example:

`T_all_PCFi_gl<-envelope(T_all_ppp,fun=pcfinhom,nsim=39,verbose=T, 
                      simulate=expression(rpoispp(den_tr[["T_all"]])), #density in all transects
                      correction="trans",global=T,
                      savefuns = T, savepatterns = T)`

However, if I want to check the results by the DCLF-test,

```
dclf.test(T_all_PCFi_gl)
```

I still get this error-message:

```
Error in data.frame(r = rvals, obs = fX, mmean = m, lo = lo, hi = hi):arguments imply differing number of rows: 55, 56
```

I have traced the problem to the 'envelope'-object, where "simfun" has one more observation than the dataframe itself, but what do I do wrong? How can I fix this and get the DCLF-test working properly?

The strangest thing is that it doesn't happen in all 7 'pcfcross.inhom' 'envelope'-objects, but apparently only for those with larger number of individuals (>700).

Is it my mistake (if yes, where in the code?), or is it a bug?

Thank you very much in advance for answer!
(I am sorry for not uploading the data, but they are to be published in an article)

**EDIT:**
Here is output from traceback (,3):
    `> traceback(,3)
    8: stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
       paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
    7: data.frame(r = rvals, obs = fX, mmean = m, lo = lo, hi = hi)
    6: (function (Y, ..., rvals = NULL, observed = NULL, theory = NULL, 
       funX = NULL, nsim = NULL, nsim2 = NULL, jsim = NULL, jsim.mean = NULL, 
       type = c("pointwise", "global", "variance"), alternative = 
    c("two.sided", 
    ...
    5: do.call(envelope.matrix, resolve.defaults(list(Y = as.matrix(df)), 
       aargh, list(type = etype, csr = csr, funX = Y, Yname = Yname, 
           weights = wt), .StripNull = TRUE))
    4: envelope.envelope(X, ..., savefuns = TRUE, savepatterns = savepatterns, 
       Yname = Xname, verbose = verbose)
    3: envelope(X, ..., savefuns = TRUE, savepatterns = savepatterns, 
       Yname = Xname, verbose = verbose)
    2: envelopeTest(X, ..., exponent = 2, alternative = alternative, 
       rinterval = rinterval, leaveout = leaveout, scale = scale, 
       clamp = clamp, interpolate = interpolate, Xname = Xname)
    1: dclf.test(colcl_b1_pcf, alternative = "greater")`

**Edit 2:**
After upgrade to version `1.58-2.042`:

```
> dclf.test(colcl_b5_pcf)
Error in (function (Y, ..., rvals = NULL, observed = NULL, theory = NULL,  
: 
nrow(funX) == nrow(Y) is not TRUE`

> traceback(,3)
8: stop(simpleError(msg, call = sys.call(-1)))
7: stopifnot(nrow(funX) == nrow(Y))
6: (function (Y, ..., rvals = NULL, observed = NULL, theory = NULL, 
   funX = NULL, nsim = NULL, nsim2 = NULL, jsim = NULL, jsim.mean = NULL, 
   type = c("pointwise", "global", "variance"), alternative = 
c("two.sided", 
...
5: do.call(envelope.matrix, resolve.defaults(list(Y = as.matrix(df)), 
   aargh, list(type = etype, csr = csr, funX = Y, Yname = Yname, 
       weights = wt), .StripNull = TRUE))
4: envelope.envelope(X, ..., savefuns = TRUE, savepatterns = savepatterns, 
   Yname = Xname, verbose = verbose)
3: envelope(X, ..., savefuns = TRUE, savepatterns = savepatterns, 
   Yname = Xname, verbose = verbose)
2: envelopeTest(X, ..., exponent = 2, alternative = alternative, 
   rinterval = rinterval, leaveout = leaveout, scale = scale, 
   clamp = clamp, interpolate = interpolate, Xname = Xname)
1: dclf.test(colcl_b5_pcf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug in `spatstat` but I have not been able to reproduce it. Without your data, I may be unable to find the bug.

Please re-run the example and after an error occurs, type `traceback(,3)` and capture the printed output. This may help me track down the bug.

You could also try including the argument `ginterval` in the call to `envelope`. The problem is probably related to the default rule for calculating `ginterval`.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply and advice! I will check the argument 'ginterval', and I will come back with output from 'traceback(,3)'.

Comment: I have specified `ginterval` to  c(0,15) in `envelope`-call; it helped for the total dataset `envelope`-object (no error in `dclf.test` anymore), but unfortunately not for the sub-sets. See output from `traceback(,3)` in edited question (output was too long for a comment).

Comment: In the envelope command, please try omitting the argument ‘global’, and then retry the dclf.test on the resulting object.

Comment: Please install the latest development version of `spatstat` (version `1.58-2.041`) from [github](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat) and re-try your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try both upgrading to version `1.58-2.041`, and running the `envelope` with `global = F`.

Comment: Running `envelope` with `global = F` in `spatstat`-version `1.58-2` (i.e. CRAN-version) worked fine, i.e. no error in subsequent `dclf.test`.I have some issues with  installing `spatstat` development version `1.58-2.041`, but I will try to get it working as soon as possible, to test if I can use `global = T`.

Comment: I have upgraded to `spatstat`-version `1.58-2.042` from [GitHub](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat). Unfortunately, after re-running the `envelope`-command with `global = T`, an error similar/identical to the previous one occurred (see Edit 2).

Comment: The question was answered by @AdrianBaddeley: this was apparently a bug, fixed in `spatstat` version [1.58-2.043](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat).